# Fluid Layout Pure CSS

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am trying to create a fluid layout.
Everything is working FF, Chrome, Safari and IE8

This just doesn't work in IE7. I am sure it's a problem with the floated containers.
Tried to do a couple clear fixes, but that didn't seem to work. Just not sure what I am missing, any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

If you compare how it renders in IE7 to IE8 a few things I noticed:

- The background-color for the first row is the background color of the
  container
- The bottom border and margin of the container are missing

Here is a live example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7PVk/)

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="container layout">
    <div class="containerContent row">

        <div class="group">
            <div class="column">
               <div class="component">
                Player 1:
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="component">
                    <input class="text" type="text"/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="groupByTwo group">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="component">
                Player 2:
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="component">
                    <input class="text" type="text"/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="clearFix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.container{
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color:  #aaa;  
}

.containerContent{
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.group{  
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.column{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.component{
    padding: 5px;   
}

.clearFix{
  clear: both;   
}
```

Comment: This may be a hasLayout issue.  Try giving the container(s) of your floated elements a height:1% style.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a hasLayout issue, like skybondsor said.

The best way I've seen for clearing floats is as such:

```
.floatParent {
    zoom: 1; <-- this is for IE7
}
.floatParent:after { <-- this is for all the good browsers
    content: "\0020"; 
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

Then you can remove that anti-semantic clearfix div from the markup, and just have something clean like this:

```
<div class="floatParent">
    <div class="floating">I FLOAT!</div>
    <div class="floating">WHOA ME TOO!</div>
</div>
```

Then it's just a matter of fixing up those pesky form fields, which for some reason always cause layout issues (by dropping on to the next line).